# How to get test coverage for kotlin common?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, code-coverage

How to get test coverage for kotlin common in mpp project in IntelliJ IDEA same as for java code?
[image: example]

Comment: Not clear what's "Kotlin common" in this case? Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: I mean common part of mpp project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (Kotlin IDEA plugin 1.4.10) code coverage doesn't work for Common source sets of MPP (multiplatform) projects. This is a known limitation, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31983.